# What is the purpose of @reflectable in Polymer Dart 1.0.0?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I already know some of the places I have to use @reflectable in like this

```
@property String get name Band =>_nameBand;
@reflectable void set nameBand(val) {
   _nameBand = val;
   notifyPath('nameBand', _nameBand;
}
```

And for events triggered by, say, clicking an element.

```
<paper-button on-click="clicked"></paper-button>
```

Inside the elements class definition where you define the event handler method that you want to be called on the on-click event.

```
... 
@reflectable
void clicked([_, __]) {
   ... 
}
```

And without the @reflectable annotation, Polymer won't be able to find either the setter or the method you want to be used whenever the paper-button is clicked. Why is @reflectable needed, as in, what is its purpose?

I realise I seem to be answering my own question, but I would love some clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

without the `@reflectable` annotation the tree shaker will throw away all the meta data needed by polymer. Polymer uses https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable to allow it to use a limited amount of reflection without bloating the code size too much.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct, but I appreciate +Günter Zöchbauer answer, which gives me info on where @reflectable is needed

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Anders' answer...
you need to annotate every method with `@reflectable` that you want expose to Polymer to be used as event handler (`on-tap="clickHandler"`) or for bindings with funciton calls like `attribute-name="{{computeValue(someName)}}"`.
You also need to annotate every field in a model class you want to bind to

```
Person extends JsProxy {
  @reflectable String firstName;
  @reflectable String lastName;
}
```

Comment: So when you say model class, you're talking about an external class that your Polymer element could use to store data in, etc. Like a model representing a row in a table on a database?

Comment: Yup, I think in the Polymer docu its called complex data. If you have a class `Person` (would have been a better name in my example anyway)` and you want to use Polymer bindings to fields of that class.

Comment: And does it have to extend JsProxy?

Comment: Yes, this are the current requirements AFAIK (`JsProxy` and `@reflectable`) . I guess you can add `JsProxy` as mixin as well but I haven't checked yet.